# Taylor Series Sorting Exponents

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have a MATLAB code that generates the exponent of general Taylor series of a 3-variable function f(x, y, z). In the example below, I am calculating the 3rd order Taylor series.

```
order = 3;
nTuple = 3;
allExponents = [];
for n = 1 : order
    [~,x] = nsumk(nTuple, n); % nsumk can be downloaded from: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28340-nsumk
    allExponents = [allExponents; x]
end
```

The function generates the following coefficients:

```
0     0     1   % This means z with exponent 1; x and y with zero exponent.
0     1     0   % This means y with exponent 1; x and z with zero exponent.
1     0     0   % This means x with exponent 1; y and z with zero exponent.
0     0     2
0     1     1
0     2     0
1     0     1
1     1     0
2     0     0
0     0     3
0     1     2
0     2     1   % This means x with exponent 0, y with exponent 2 and z with exponent 1, i,e, y^2*z
0     3     0
1     0     2
1     1     1
1     2     0
2     0     1
2     1     0   % This means x with exponent 2 and y with exponent 1 and z with exponent 0, i,e, x^2*y
3     0     0
```

How can I sort them in the following form (the empty line between them is for clarity):

```
1     0     0    % x
0     1     0    % y
0     0     1    % z

2     0     0    % x^2
0     2     0    % y^2
0     0     2    % z^2

3     0     0    % x^3
0     3     0    % y^3
0     0     3    % z^3

1     1     0    % x*y
1     0     1    % x*z
0     1     1    % y*z


1     2     0    % x*y^2
1     0     2    % x*z^2
0     1     2    % y*z^2

2     1     0    % x^2*y
2     0     1    % x^2*z
0     2     1    % y^2*z

1     1     1    % x*y*z
```

Update: 
Ordering is as follows:

First x^n, y^n, z^n, where n is from 1 to the order of the Taylor series, in this particular example 3.

Then, the cross multiplication of each two variable whose exponents add to 2, e.g, xy, xz, and yz.

Then the cross multiplication of each two variables whose exponents adds to 3 with the first variable having exponent 1, i.e., xy^2, xz^2, yz^2.

Then the cross multiplication of each two variables whose exponents add to 3 with the fist variable having exponent 2, i.e., x^2y, x^2z, y^2z.

Lastly, the multiplication of all three variables whose exponents add to 3, i.e., xyz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following ordering rules should give you what you want.

In order of precedence...

1. Descending by number of variables present (number of non-zero powers).
2. Descending by order of term (sum of powers).
3. Lexicographical order of non-zero powers.
4. Lexicographical order of variables present.

Implementing these rules is a bit messy but here's the code.

```
% 1.
num_vars = sum(allExponents~=0, 2);
% 2.
order = sum(allExponents, 2);
% 3. Implemented by pushing all zero-elements to end of the row
[~,j] = sort(allExponents == 0, 2);
[i,~] = ndgrid(1:size(allExponents, 1), 1:nTuple);
sub = sub2ind(size(allExponents), i, j);
squeezed = reshape(allExponents(sub), size(allExponents));
% 4.
lex = allExponents == 0;

% Construct a key and sort
sort_term = [num_vars, order, squeezed, lex];
[~, idx] = sortrows(sort_term);
allExponents = allExponents(idx,:);
```

P.S. I'm not sure how well this generalizes to higher order or more variables. I tried to keep that in mind when constructing the solution but I didn't test.

Comment: Brilliant. I learned something very useful! Thank you @jodag!

Comment: Would you refer me to a documentation (or any other online material) where I could learn more about the approach you cleverly came up with? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about any documentation but the main idea is to create the `sort_term` or "key" associated with each row. The key is constructed so that sorting by the key results in the desired ordering. Since we have multiple rules, we construct the key with multiple sub-keys, where precedence is imposed by concatenating sub-keys left to right to form the final key. When comparing two rows, `sortrows` will only consider a lower precedence column (sub-key) when the higher precedence (more left) columns are identical.